# get return value of last expression

Tags: javascript

On the Chrome console, you can get the return value of the last expression

```
> 1+1; 2+1;
< 3
```

How to implement this function in javascript?

```
$expressions = '1+1; 2+1;' // from user input
new Function($expressions).call() // return 3, not 2
```

Can only be inserted in the last expression return statement?

Comment: The console is giving you the result of the last statement, which is the program result, and which is something you can't directly access in JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), but keep in mind that [it is not a good practice to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86513/5894241).

```js
var value = eval("1+1; 2+1;");

console.log(value);
```

Comment: The OP is already evaluating the code with `Function`, so `eval` isn't really any worse. Main difference is that `eval` can access local variables. So `eval` isn't much worse than evaluating any other code, like with `<script>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `eval(expression)` instead like this:

```js
console.log(eval("1+1; 1+2"));
```